# CountDownTimer in Android ViewModel executes onFinish twice

Tags: android, kotlin, timer, android-viewmodel

I tried to implement a timer in a ViewModel that after ten seconds returns to the previous view, but it doesn't work at all. I wonder if CountDownTimer can even be used in a ViewModel.

```kotlin
class PairingScreenViewModel(
    private val routing: NavController,
) : ViewModel() {
    var content = mutableStateOf(10)
    var counter: CountDownTimer? = null

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            delay(1000L)
            counter = object : CountDownTimer(9000L, 1000L) {
                override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                    content.value = content.value.dec()
                }

                override fun onFinish() {
                    routing.popBackStack() // Go back twice. WHY?
                }
            }.start()
        }
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared() // It seems that it never runs.
        counter?.cancel()
    }

    fun onButtonClicked() = viewModelScope.launch {
        counter?.cancel() // It doesn't cancel the timer.
        routing.navigate("next-route")
    }
}
```

EDIT: This is my MainActivity.kt, I am probably doing something wrong with NavHostController.
This is the first time I use androidx.navigation:navigation-compose.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val routing = rememberNavController()
            val heading = "MyApplication"
            AndroidNavigationDemoTheme {
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    Scaffold(
                        topBar = {
                            TopAppBar(
                                title = { Text(heading, textAlign = TextAlign.Center, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) }
                            )
                        },
                        content = {
                            Router(routing)
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Router(routing: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(
        navController = routing,
        startDestination = "welcome"
    ) {
        composable("welcome") {
            WelcomeScreen(routing)
        }
        composable("hisense") {
            HisenseScreen(HisenseScreenViewModel(routing))
        }
        composable("pairing") {
            PairingScreen(PairingScreenViewModel(routing))
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I made MCVE (just with timer), and it worked correctly `onTick 8839
 onTick 7838
 onTick 6838
 onTick 5837
 onTick 4834
 onTick 3832
 onTick 2830
 onTick 1818
 onTick 817
 onFinish`.
Did you try debugging your code?

Comment: I suspect you are somehow creating two instances of your ViewModel.

Comment: I edited my first post with the contents of my MainActivity.kt.

Answer (score 0):

I have to remove ViewModel from the NavHost.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Router(routing: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(
        navController = routing,
        startDestination = "welcome"
    ) {
        composable("welcome") {
            WelcomeScreen(routing)
        }
        // ...
        composable("pairing") {
            PairingScreen(routing)
        }
        // ..
    }
}
```

And set the ViewModel from the composable.

```kotlin
class PairingScreenViewModelFactory(private val routing: NavController) :
    ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory() {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T = PairingScreenViewModel(routing) as T
}

@Composable
fun PairingScreen(routing: NavController) {
    val viewModel: PairingScreenViewModel = viewModel(factory = PairingScreenViewModelFactory(routing))
    // ...
}
```

And everything is working like a charm.